# How to bundle Angular $http.get() calls?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller that needs to retrieve two separate REST resources that will populate two dropdowns. I would like to avoid populating either of them until both $http.get() calls have returned, so that the dropdowns appear to be populated at the same time, instead of trickling in one after the other.

Is it possible to bundle $http.get() calls and elegantly set the $scope variables for both returned arrays, without having to write state logic for both scenarios, e.g. a returns before b, b returns before a?

Comment: FYI - the question title says "chain" but the body describes a join.  Not sure if an edit is appropriate here.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The return value of calling the Angular [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http) function is a `Promise` object using [$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q) (a promise/deferred implementation inspired by [Kris Kowal's Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)).

Take a look at the `$q.all(promises)` method documentation:

> Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when
>   all of the input promises are resolved.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - promises – `{Array.<Promise>}` – An array of promises.
>
> **Returns**
>
> `{Promise}` – Returns a single promise that will be resolved with an array of values, each value corresponding to the promise at the same index in the promises array. If any of the `promises` is resolved with a rejection, this resulting promise will be resolved with the same rejection.

You can use `$q.all` to "join" the results of your http calls, with code similar to:

```
app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $q) {

  $q.all([
    $http.get('/someUrl1'),
    $http.get('/someUrl2')
  ]).then(function(results) {
     /* your logic here */
  });
}
```

Comment: What happens to the error()? Will that be available in the array of results?

Comment: see the documentation note on any rejection, results in a rejection

Comment: This is not "chain" but "bundled"

Comment: @brushleaf if you want to handle errors, just add a second function in then call after success callback.

Comment: @Smarty_Twiti This is the answer to the problem described, but "chain" in the title is misleading (as percebus commented)

Comment: And to handle the results (in the "your logic here" section) you would do something like this: 
`var url1Data = response[0].data;
var url2Data = response[1].data;`

Answer (score 6):

do you mean something like this:

```
function someController( $scope, $http, $q ) {
    var first_meth = $http.get("first_url"),
        second_meth = $http.get("second_url");
    $q.all([first_meth, second_meth]).then(function(all_your_results_array) { 
        //here you'll get results for both the calls
    });
}
```

Ref: [Angular JS Doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Async javsscript library here: https://github.com/caolan/async.

Use the series call.  It will make the 2 calls and then call one callback when both are done.