# Multiple HTTP requests in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

So this my controller:

```
app.controller('dbCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("http://private-abc.apiary-mock.com/bus")
.success(function(response) {
 $scope.network = response.networkupdates;});
 });
```

What I wanted to do next is call a 2nd HTTP request, I guess in terms of best practice would it be best to create a 2nd controller to call the 2nd HTTP or would it be best to include the 2nd HTTP call in this current controller (and if so, how?)
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to chain Angular $http.get() calls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726377/how-to-chain-angular-http-get-calls)

Comment: Not really necessary to create another controller but we don't know the extent of your app either .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So one of the cool aspects of using promises is that they can be chained. So in your case, you are calling:

```
$http.get("http://private-abc.apiary-mock.com/bus")
```

Which returns a promise that you can then chain to another promise like so:

```
var requests = $http.get("http://private-abc.apiary-mock.com/bus").then(function(response) {
    $scope.network = response.networkupdates;
    // make second get call and return it to chain the promises
    return $http.get("some-other-endpoint").then(function(otherResponse) {
        // you can do something here with the response data
        return otherResponse;
    });
});
```

What you have now is two chained promises that will return the final value, so if you call this later:

```
requests.then(function(otherResponse) {
    // or you can do something here
    doSomething(otherResponse);
});
```

As far as best practices for Angular, I would say you are better off creating a service or factory to handle any and all http requests. Controllers are really just meant to bind data to the view; services are where your business logic and data population should happen.

Comment: not even clear that the calls are related to each other and even need to be chained

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `$http` calls in the same controller.

The `$http` service is a function which takes a single argument — a configuration object — that is used to generate an HTTP request and returns a `promise` with two $http specific methods: `success and error`. It internally uses `$q` (a promise/deferred implementation inspired by Kris Kowal's Q).

If your two `$http` are independent of each other you use the `$q.all` to "join" the results of your http calls.

Example :

```
$q.all([
    $http.get("http://private-abc.apiary-mock.com/bus"),
    $http.get('/someUrl')
  ]).then(function(results) {
     $scope.network = results[0];
     $scope.whatevername= results[1]

  });
}
```

If your http calls are dependent on one another then you can use the concept of `chaining`.

for example:

```
$http.get("http://private-abc.apiary-mock.com/bus").then(function(result) {
    $scope.network = result.networkupdates;    
    return $http.get("someurl").then(function(res) {        
        return res;
    });
});
```

For refernce of `q` you can see https://github.com/kriskowal/q

For refernce of  `$q service` you can see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q