# Chaining Angular Functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know this has been asked before but I'm trying to figure out how to chain functions that contain ajax calls.  What I have is:

```
$scope.firstFunc();
$scope.secondFunc();
```

secondFunc checks a scope value that is set from firstFunc.  How can I chain this?

Comment: You need to return and use promises.

Comment: @slaks you could simply return the $scope from each of the methods, no?

Comment: "I know this has been asked before". What didn't you understand about the previous questions' answers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to chain Angular $http.get() calls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726377/how-to-chain-angular-http-get-calls)

Answer (score 0):

If for example you have the following functions:

```
$scope.firstFunc = function() {
    return $http
        .get('/api/objects')
        .then(function(data) {
            $scope.data = data;
        });
};

$scope.secondFunc = function() {
    return $http
        .get('/api/otherObjects')
        .then(function(data) {
            // do something with new 'data' and with $scope.data
        });
};
```

you could call them in order like this:

```
$scope.firstFunc().then($scope.secondFunc);
```

Assuming I understood correctly.

`$scope.firstFunc()` returned the Promise `$http.get` returned (after it finished with its first `.then` chain)

And then, we chained another `.then` for that same Promise, and told it to execute `$scope.secondFunc`.

You could also just use the first ajax call's response data directly by using the following (if it fits your needs):

```
$scope.firstFunc = function() {
    return $http
        .get('/api/objects');
};

$scope.secondFunc = function(previousData) {
    return $http
        .get('/api/otherObjects')
        .then(function(data) {
            // do something with 'previousData' from the previous call from $scope.firstFunc
        });
};
```

and call everything with `$scope.firstFunc().then($scope.secondFunc)` so that `$scope.secondFunc` received `$scope.firstFunc()`'s data directly instead of passing through the `$scope` if that's somehow what you wanted in the first place, otherwise, the first part of this answer would do I think.

Hope this helped!